# Was Lorentz aware of Le Sage theory?

Tags: gravity

I just wondered if [Lorentz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hendrik_Lorentz) was aware of [Le Sage theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Le_Sage%27s_theory_of_gravitation). Seems like he uses similar math. Is there any direct quote from Lorentz regarding Le Sage gravity?

Comment: He was aware of it, Anti. See [the Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Le_Sage%27s_theory_of_gravitation&oldid=867302622#Wave_models).